How to Ensure Chunk Size Does Not Exceed Model’s Input Token Limit in Oracle AI Vector Search?
I am relatively new to semantic search and currently working with Oracle AI Vector Search. I need some clarification on how to properly prepare input text for vector generation without exceeding the model's maximum input sequence length.
The AI Vector Search User Guide provides detailed information about the chunking functions, aiming to create semantically coherent chunks that aren't too large. However, while chunk size can be adjusted, it only reflects the number of characters or words, not the input tokens. As far as I know, models impose limits based on the number of input tokens rather than character length.
For example, when text is split by words, chunk sizes vary due to differences in word lengths. How can I ensure that my chunks do not exceed the input token size of the model I’m using? There seems to be no functionality to generate tokens for chunks in advance to verify their size. I need to avoid the risk of truncating content when generating vectors, as the chunks may be too large.
To provide more specifics: I am using the preconfigured model sentence-transformers/paraphrase-multilingual-mpnet-base-v2. According to the configuration parameters (retrieved via EmbeddingModelConfig.show_preconfigured(include_properties=True, model_name='sentence-transformers/paraphrase-multilingual-mpnet-base-v2')), the maximum input length is set to 512 tokens. However, on Hugging Face, the model properties mention a maximum input length of 128 tokens and do_lower_case: False, which differs from the preconfigured settings. (https://huggingface.co/sentence-transformers/paraphrase-multilingual-mpnet-base-v2#full-model-architecture)
For chunking, I used the following test parameters: split by words, max 100, overlap 10, split recursively. My test data resulted in a chunk with a maximum character length of 858.
So my main question is: How can I assess whether my chunk size is appropriate, ensuring that the token limit of the model is not exceeded? Is there any functionality within Oracle AI Vector Search to determine this, and how can I avoid exceeding the input token limit during chunking, which is the primary reason chunking is necessary?
I would appreciate any insights or suggestions.
Thank you!
